# Hasfile property of FileUpload is always false in GridView

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview, file-upload, updatepanel

I am using FileUpload in GridView and this GridView is in UPdatePanel. This  FileUpload is in footer of the GridView. I am uploading selected file in this FileUploader on a link button in same GridView. BUT when on uploading HasFile property is false.

I have google for this problem and only solution is to put button in

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
```

But my FileUPloader is in GridView.

Any help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option available to you as a workaround is to use the [Ajax Upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) jQuery plugin.  An example on that page describes how to access the uploaded file in asp.net.  Search for "IHttpHandler"

Answer (score 1):

The FileUpload control relies on a normal `<input type="file" />` html element, and that doesn't do anything until you submit the html form element... meaning you need a full postback rather than ajax update to see the file.